# Inline function not resolving ambiguity

Tags: c++, inline

```
//myheader.h

namespace abc{
   int func(int x) { return 10 + x;}
   inline int callfunc(int a){ return func(a); }
}


//global.h

int func(int x){ return 10 + x; }
```

In the example above, when the code is compiled, and even if the inline function are not called at any place for now, it returns an error to resolve the ambiguity for the `func(int x)`. Why doesn't inline function take the existing definition that is already present in the `namespace abc`?

Comment: `inline` functions are still compiled even if not invoked, so *"even if the inline function are not called at any place for now, it returns an error"* reveals your misunderstanding of what the `inline` keyword does. It's only *guaranteed* effect is to suppress the One Definition Rule (ODR) for that function. All other behavior is compiler-specific. Also, the code you have presented here is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. ([It works for me](http://ideone.com/ATfldv).)

Comment: Does your error go away with specificity such as { return abc::func( a ); }

Comment: Why doesn't it resolve the ambiguity from the function definition that is already present in the current namespace. ?

Comment: Are you including the "global.h" header into multiple source files?

Comment: @Srikan It does -- see the link in my previous comment. The code you have put in your question does not reproduce the problem. Please produce the smallest possible *one file* reproduction of the issue and add that to your question.

Comment: yes I need to include global.h

Comment: [Works for me if the headers are only used in at most one translation unit](https://ideone.com/TTg0m7)

Comment: Neither `abc::func` nor `::func` are inline functions, and both have external linkage. By including those definitions into multiple source files, you're violating the One Definition Rule. That rule says, in this case, that no function with external linkage and not being `inline` may have more than one definition in the *whole program*.

Comment: Lookup is complicated, and you are omitting important details. If the code is as you laid out, there would be no ambiguity, there could be if you had a using declaration inside the namespace for the global function, or if you had a using directive for the namespace somewhere else and you tried to call the function from the global namespace... but not with just the code above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your error is not reproducible from posted code - these headers compile without problems when included in single .cpp file. So you really should post your .cpp files. It's .cpp files that are actually compiled, not headers, so without them we don't get the whole picture.
2. You should've posted an actual error, not just your impression of it. With your description we can't even be sure if it's compiler error or linker error.

Nevertheless, I'll propose some possible solutions for your problem.

1. Try to specify namespace in call to the func:

   `inline int callfunc(int a){ return abc::func(a); }`
2. You really shouldn't define non-inline functions in headers, you'll get linker errors if you include your headers in more than one .cpp file.
   So you should keep definitions in .cpp and only declarations in .h files like it was meant to be.